# Google Apps Script send email through spreadsheet not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with some Google Script stuff. Basically, my goal is to have the script check to see if a client's case was resolved and then send an email to them that the issue has been resolved. I've gotten the logic done on when to send an email, but every time I try and implement it into the spreadsheet, I get the error:

`Error
You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail (line 8).`

I've got a  simple function to test the functionality of it, and when run in the script editor it works fine, but not on the spreadsheet. Here is my sample function:

```
function myFunction(row) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rng = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
var ara = rng.getValues();
var email = ara[0][0];
MailApp.sendEmail(email, "TEST", "This is a test of sendEmail().");
return "Email sent.";}
```

Comment: "implement it into the spreadsheet" means what, using it as a function from a spreadsheet cell? Read about "Apps Script Custom Functions" to learn why. The error is correct. Consider also what it means if that function actually could be called as a custom function --- how many emails would get sent? when would they get sent? (PS: look at what the function's arguments actually are, inside the function, by using `console` or `Logger`, and compare that to you what you expected)

Comment: Yeah, so how I will call it would basically on a cell do: =myFunction(ROW()). And then in my full code it would have certain checks so that it wouldn't send an email every time you refresh the page.

Comment: Look into timed triggers or adding a menu.  Custom functions don't have authority to send mail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script - DriveApp.getFilesByName - Error (No Permission)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860962/google-script-driveapp-getfilesbyname-error-no-permission)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Apps Script Custom Functions documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#permissions):

> If your custom function throws the error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus **cannot** be used in a custom function.
>
> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.

#### Method 1

Basically, you can replicate the wanted behavior of the two functions above with this:

```
function SendEmail() {
   var message = "This is your response";
   var subject = "You have feed back in the parking lot";
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var textrange = ss.getRange("F2");
   var emailAddress = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
   if (textrange.isBlank() == false)
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

And in order to trigger the execution of this function, you can make use of [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and choose one which is the most convenient for your use-case.

#### Method 2

You can also create a custom menu and with the option of triggering the above function. You only need to add this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("My Menu")
      .addItem("Send Email", "SendEmail")
      .addToUi();
}
```

And this is how it will look like on the Spreadsheet:

[image: custom menu]

### Reference

- [Apps Script Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions);
- [Apps Script Range Class - isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank);
- [Apps Script Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus);
- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem today "You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail".

I solved this by doing the next steps:

- open "Tools" -> "Script editor"
- in "Script editor" click on "View" -> "Show manifest file"
- open the "appscript.json" file that appeared in the left section of your screen and add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail" to the oauthScopes, like this:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"],
}
```

PS: I assigned the script to an image, which basically acts like a button.

Comment: I've found other documentation that shows this as the answer, and it makes sense, but it is not working for me. Is there anything you need to do, special, after adding the scopes to the appscript.json file?